# transfer between different account

Tags: transactions

I'm living in Turkey and I bought some bitcoins from here.
If, for example, I have a neighbour in America and he bought bitcoin from a different platform, can I transfer my bitcoins to him? And can he transfer it to me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Bitcoins are the same no matter where you bought them, and you can transfer them anywhere you want.

(One thing to watch out for, though, is that Bitcoin Cash is a different currency from Bitcoin, and you can't directly transfer one to the other.)

Comment: Why not? > you can't directly transfer one to the other

Comment: Because they are designed not to be interchangeable.  You can *exchange* one for the other, by finding someone willing to trade - just like you can exchange dollars for euros - but the exchange rate will vary.  You can't take 1 BCC and "transfer" it into 1 BTC.